# Tableau works with Hive, data right truncated error

Tags: hive, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau with Hive connector, when I tried to do a data extract from a hive view I created, I got an error like this:

Data right truncated

Does anyone have some clues about this error? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for time stamp fields was added to Tableau in version 8.1.9. If an older version of Tableau Desktop is being used, then upgrading Tableau Desktop and ensuring that you have [the most recent driver](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/connectors.html) should resolve the issue.

Failing that, a workaround for this error is as follows:

1. Change the time stamp fields to String when creating extracts
2. Convert these String fields to time stamp using Tableau's calculated fields or built-in formatting

Some links to help with this workaround:

- [Data Types](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#datafields_typesandroles_datatypes.html)
- [Correcting Date Fields that Tableau Interprets as Strings](http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/fixing-date-fields)
- [Date Functions](http://onlinehelp.tableausoftware.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#functions_functions_date.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Tlvalin! it's indeed an issue about Tableau version, but it seems that they fixed it in the 8.0.xx version